# How to write a sender application for ActiveMQ in Node JS

Tags: java, node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

I wanted to create implement a JMS sender app for messaging and created the same with JAVA. This is my sample code snippet in Java.

```
    try {
        factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        destination = session.createQueue("SAMPLEQUEUE");
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        try {

                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                message.setText("hello");
                producer.send(message);
                System.out.println("Sent: " + message.getText());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works fine and I am able to receive the messages with my receiver also. I want to change the sender implementation in Node JS and make it a Node JS application. I am new to Node JS didn't understand much after searching on ActiveMQ in Node JS. Any pointer to it would be really helpful.

Regards,
Subhankar

**EDIT**

I used stomp for node JS. The sample code is the following :

```
var Stomp = require('stomp-client');
var destination = '/queue/sensorstreamqueue';
var client = new Stomp('10.53.219.153', 61613, 'user', 'pass');
var     lazy    = require("lazy"),
        fs  = require("fs");



client.connect(function(sessionId) {
new lazy(fs.createReadStream('input.csv'))
     .lines
     .forEach(function(line){
         client.publish(destination, line.toString());
     }
 );   
    console.log("published");
});
```

The code works and my receiver also gets the message but then my receiver expects it to be a textMesssage format and gives the following error:

```
02-19-2015 08:42:31.288 ERROR [Thread-25] (JmsInputTransporter.handleTextMessage) Error code:401306, Severity : 3 (Error)
Error message:JMS Transporter is expected a TextMessage, received class org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage.
Error description:JMS Transporter is expected a TextMessage, received class org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage.
```

Can someone help me how can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you include your receiver code?

Comment: Hi Josh,

Unfortunately the receiver is part of a component which I don't own and expects the message to be in Text Message format

Comment: To the person who has down-voted, it would be good if you could explain what you didn't like about the question. May be I can improve next time!!

Comment: I am noticing a similar issue in what I'm working on. Sending a message through stomp-client ends up in the Java application as a ByteSequence in the content property, but is should be plain text in the text property. I'll check back in if I find something.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [activemq-node](https://github.com/zmhassan/activemq-node.js) module, or you can enable the [STOMP protocol](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) on ActiveMQ and use [this node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stomp-client) library.

Comment: Hi Josh,

Thank you very much for your help. I tried with stomp and it worked. However there is a little issue I am facing, could you please see my edit for more details and help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a header:

```
client.publish(destination, 'your content', {
    "amq-msg-type": "text"
});
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2833